# regex for code fence markdown. Is it simple?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find **regex for code fence markdown**.

````
```

some code

```
````

it is supposed to match the pattern, then stored in Array of Javascript

Firstly I made this code:

````
```+\n[\s\S]+```+
````

However, since ``` does not indicate begin-end. If I have multiple code fences, it selects whole like as a single selection like the following:

````
```

some code

```

```

some code

```
````

I investigated [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) code then found something below

```
fences: /^ *(`{3,}|~{3,}) *(\S+)? *\n([\s\S]+?)\s*\1 *(?:\n+|$)/
```

however, this seems only mathe the first hit.

What is the proper regex? If it's too complicated, I think I can construct Array with trimming the result.

If there's a elegant regex, I would chose that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s\S]+` is greedy, matching also the fence delimiters, thereby matching too much. You've got two options:

Either make the quantifier lazy, so it matches as few characters as possible:

````
/```\n[\s\S]+?```/g
````

Or use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure you don't match across fence boundaries:

````
/```\n(?:(?!```)[\s\S])+```/g
````

The `/g` global modifier allows the regex to match more than once.

Comment: \`\`\`+\n[\s\S]+?\`\`\`+  looks good enough. Thank you for great tutorial as always. @Tim